# When we define the abstract methods of an interface in a class do we 'override' or 'implement' or simply say 'define' those methods?

Tags: java, interface

Is the show() method in class B 'overridden', 'implemented' or simply 'defined'?

```
interface A
{
    void show();
}

class B implements A
{
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("What is the proper term to explain?");
    }
}
```

Comment: implemented is better

Comment: I would say "implement" is the most correct, as "override" would suggest it already has an implementation that is being overridden, and "define" would only be true in the context of class "B"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856645/abstract-method-implementation-vs-abstract-method-overriding-do-these-two-mean (The JLS answer is there, anyway. In this example, `show` is both overridden and implemented.)

Comment: Regardless of which terminology you use, you should still use the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer, we `override` those methods, why?

Because this represents the concept of polymorphic statement, Remember

```
List<String> aa = new ArrayList<>();
// List => interface
// ArrayList => class
aa.add("polymorphic statment");
```

Polymorphic statement and overiding go hand in hand.

Although any class also has the option to implement an interface by declaring itself `abstract` and no need to `override` any method.

Note: Apply the same concept in any IDE, will guide you to add `@Override` annotation.

Comment: But overriding suggest replacing an existing implementation, which is not the case for interfaces (if we except defaults)

Comment: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^          I got the above error message when used the '@Override' annotation in wrong context. I think Java uses the same annotation for implementing a method from an interface & overriding a method in a subclass.

Comment: @PratipChakraborty you must be doing something wrong, access modifier, param etc. check out [**this demo to verify your code**](https://ideone.com/viSkeY)

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I wanted some geeks' advice to solve the controversy. As there is no separate annotation that denotes implementing a method from an interface so '@Override' is being used. Although both the concepts are a bit similar, wanting more light on the topic by the experts in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Any other views @Pavneet_Singh because what I think is the IDE leads to '@Override' annotation due to absence of any other appropriate annotation that can define the same. Anyway thank you for your precious time & opinion.

Comment: @PratipChakraborty see, the meaning of implementation(even in programming) is providing the context or to do something particular so either we override (same as implement to do something particular) or we simply just inherit the methods(if class is abstract)

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh please have a look ----  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking I say "override" to mean redefining an inherited behavior and I keep "implement" to mean defining a behavior (not implemented yet).

So I would say that  `B` implements `show()`.

And the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) seems to go in this way :

> If a non-abstract method `mC` overrides an abstract method `mA` from a
>   class `C`, then `mC` is said to implement `mA` from `C`.

The [oracle example documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) seems to says that `override` is to redefine a behavior too :

> The ability of a subclass to override a method allows a class to
>   inherit from a superclass whose behavior is "close enough" **and then to
>   modify behavior as needed**. The overriding method has the same name,
>   number and type of parameters, and return type as the method that it
>   overrides. An overriding method can also return a subtype of the type
>   returned by the overridden method. This subtype is called a covariant
>   return type.

Note that the `java.lang.Override` annotation doesn't say the contrary (emphasis is mine) :

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method
>   declaration in a supertype. If a method is annotated with this
>   annotation type compilers are required to generate an error message
>   unless at least one of the following conditions hold:
>
> The method does **override** or **implement** a method declared in a
>   supertype.
>
> The method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any
>   public method declared in Object.

The API could have provided `@Implement` additionally to the `@Override` annotation.
But it seems rather clumsy to have both. So they probably kept a single one : `@Override` to convey the two things.

Comment: The annotation states "does override or implement a method declared in a supertype" => in my understanding, *override* is intended for abstract classes and *implement* for interfaces.

Comment: @Joel But you can override a concrete method defined in an inherited class. No ?

Answer (score 0):

The method `show()` in class `B` implements the method declared in interface `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You should say implement because `override` means that you are overwriting some existing method which is not true in case of interfaces. Interfaces cannot contain method definitions, they merely specify a contract.

Comment: (except when there's a default implementation - since java 8)

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing this out. However, I am am not able to think of a case where this would be useful (why not use an abstract class?)

Comment: Well it's similar indeed with abstract classes, but sometimes you really want that in an interface, for example when the implementing class implements several interfaces or already extends some abstract class. But it clearly must not be over-used or it would lead to terrible design.

Comment: I agree, overusing this would lead to terrible design